# unixtime в sql и pl/sql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, дата, plsql

Здравствуйте!
Есть в БД **oracle**  *WORK_DATE (DATE)* со значением `01/04/2016 9:00:00`, делаю в `toad` из него `unixtime`

```
 round((AG.WORK_DATE - to_date('01011970','ddmmyyyy'))*24*60*60) as to_unix
```

и получаю `1459501200`

То же самое делаю в БД **mysql**

```
select UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-04-01 09:00:00')
```

и получаю `1459483200`

Почему? Что я делаю неправильно?

Смылс в том, что у меня в `oracle` даты в таблице хранятся в формате `date`, а в `mysql` даты в `unixtime`, и мне нужно инфу из `oracle` в `mysql` перетащить и я пытаюсь `date` в `unixtime` перевести, но не получается.

Comment: Разница - 5 часов. Таймзона какая? UNIX_TIMESTAMP работает от GMT+0.

Comment: @Zufir , а как это посмотреть? На сервере с oracle - YEKT

Comment: Часовая зона МСК+2 (в настоящее время — UTC+5). Делайте поправку на это.

Comment: @Zufir плюсовать в оракле 5 часов что ли просто? Как это в текущем селекте сделать?

Comment: Если в оракле - то минусовать.

Comment: Всем спасибо, сделал так: round(((AG.WORK_DATE - 5/24) - to_date('01011970','ddmmyyyy'))*24*60*60) as to_unix

Comment: На самом деле ваша проблема серьезнее. Вам никто не мешает вычесть/прибавить константу 3*60. Но это текущее смещение времени. Но когда переводят стрелки на зиму/лето смещение меняется. А в datetime поле в БД временная зона не хранится. Если вы конвертируете даты близкие к текущей - то куда ни шло. Но если у вас там произвольные даты, вам надо учитывать для какой даты какое смещение действовало, и это проблема ...

Comment: @Mike мне это надо за 2 последних месяца. Если не ошибаюсь, в ближайшие 2 месяца стрелки не переводили...

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в разных часовых поясах на серверах oracle и mysql. Спасибо @Zufir

Сделал так:

```
round(((AG.WORK_DATE - 5/24) - to_date('01011970','ddmmyyyy'))*24*60*60) as to_unix
```